# Translate text in a html text using python

Tags: html, python-3.x, language-translation

I have written an API that translates text from english to Hindi language. However, if the text that is passed is an html text, then my code fails.

How do I get this right?

1. I have tried using [py-translate](https://pythonhosted.org/py-translate/devs/api.html), but this package is not able to convert html texts properly.
2. I have also tried using googleclient package, it is able to convert html text but can handle only one request at a time.

My API should be handle multiple requests and also be able to deal with html text translation.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @RayButterworth, it has all to do with translation. The two libraries are translating libraries which have different problems. One works well with html but has multiple requests problem while the other has issues with translating html text.